# Error in adding abline to scatterplot in R

Tags: r, regression

## scatterplot

```
abundance = data.frame(lncount = c(13, 865, 1800), lnedna = c(4.72, 5.05,   5.22,   5.24,
                                                         5.36,  5.71,   5.63,   5.97,
                                                         6.08,  6.20,   6.43,   6.54))
xyplot(lnedna ~ lncount, data = abundance, 
   xlab = "Mussel Count by Snorkel Survey",
   ylab = "eDNA concentraion (gene sequence/Liter) on log scale", 
   main = "Mussel Abundance")
```

## Add fit lines

```
abline(lm(lnedna ~ lncount))
```

This is the error I keep getting when trying to add the regression line: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lnedna' not found

lnedna is working fine for making the scatter plot, why is it not working to add the regression line?

Comment: Pass the data to the `lm` function: `lm(lnedna ~ lncount, data=abundance)`

Comment: On a sidenote, must you use `xyplot()`?

Comment: Why not `plot()`?

Comment: @storaged and @ InfiniteFlashChess  I also tried your suggestions  #Add fit lines
    abline(lm(lnedna ~ lncount, data = abundance))  but then I get this error: Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet. Further I tried just plot() and get the same error

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to add the `abline` in the `xyplot` call:

```
lattice::xyplot(lnedna ~ lncount, data = abundance, 
                panel = function(x, y) {
                  lattice::panel.xyplot(x, y)
                  lattice::panel.abline(lm(y ~ x))
                },
                xlab = "Mussel Count by Snorkel Survey",
                ylab = "eDNA concentraion (gene sequence/Liter) on log scale", 
                main = "Mussel Abundance")
```

From this question: [How to add abline with lattice xyplot function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949766/how-to-add-abline-with-lattice-xyplot-function)

Comment: this is part of the problem, but not the whole thing. `xyplot()` doesn't seem to pair well with `abline(lm(lnedna ~ ......))`

Comment: Thanks @InfiniteFlashChess have edited the answer to use `xyplot`

Comment: Thank you @hrabel.  Any tips/code for adding r squared value to the plot?

Comment: @Ellen, `latticeExtra` claims to have a function for this: http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/man/panel.lmlineq.html. Haven't tried it but hopefully works!

Comment: all you need to do is add `panel.text()` to hrabel's code, as i have done in my answer above (separate from hrabel's code here.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to repoduce your answer using `plot()`. Thanks to `hrabel` for the lattice answer. Credit to him for that one.

**ggplot2**

```
library(ggplot2)

fit <- lm(lnedna ~ lncount, data = abundance)


ggplot(data = abundance, aes(x = lncount, y = lnedna))+
geom_point()+
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)+
xlab("Mussel Count by Snorkel Survey")+
ylab("eDNA concentraion (gene sequence/Liter) on log scale")+
ggtitle("Mussel Abundance")+
annotate("text" ,x = 1300, y = 6.13, label = paste("R-squared = ", summary(fit)$r.squared))
```

[image]

**lattice** (from hrabel below)

```
lattice::xyplot(lnedna ~ lncount, data = abundance, 
                panel = function(x, y) {
                  lattice::panel.xyplot(x, y)
                  lattice::panel.abline(lm(y ~ x))
                  lattice::panel.text(1300, 6.13, paste("R-squared = ", summary(fit)$r.squared), sep = "")
                },
                xlab = "Mussel Count by Snorkel Survey",
                ylab = "eDNA concentraion (gene sequence/Liter) on log scale", 
                main = "Mussel Abundance")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ hrabel and @InfiniteFlashChess - is there something I am supposed to do to give you all credit?

Comment: You can `checkmark` the user whom you think provided the answer you wanted. Note that you can only checkmark one user.

Comment: @Ellen : you can also up vote  (click the up arrow) either or both questions. [Some info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)