# Take the mean of similarly named columns at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

In my data.frame below, except the first two columns (`person_id` and `gender`), column names have been grouped together by names. For example, the  `audio_vocab` columns are 7 columns: `audio_vocab_01`, ..., `audio_vocab_07`.

I was wondering how I could take the mean of these similarly named columns in my data.frame and replace the resulting column for all its constituent columns (e.g., instead of the original 7 `audio_vocab` columns, just need one `audio_vocab_mean` column).

How can I do this for all my similarly named columns at once?

```
w2 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/n/master/w2.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split.default` to split similar named columns and take their row-wise mean.

```
cols <- 1:2
temp <- w2[-cols]
cbind(w2[cols], sapply(split.default(temp, 
                   sub('_\\d+', '', names(temp))), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE))


#  person_id gender audio_vocab ctest dictation elicited_speech text_vocab
#1         1   MALE       0.837 0.800    0.5011           0.866      0.877
#2         2   MALE       0.909 0.957    0.7348           0.926      0.937
#3         3 FEMALE       0.826 0.737    0.5179           0.771      0.711
#4         4 FEMALE       0.775 0.591    0.5735           0.645      0.736
#5         5   MALE       0.473 0.548    0.0117           0.737      0.704
#6         6  OTHER       0.635 0.729    0.4294           0.669      0.852
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

We can loop over the `unique` column names by extracting the prefix part and  get the `rowMeans`

```
un1 <- unique(sub("_\\d+$", "", names(w2)[-(1:2)]))
out <- cbind(w2[1:2], do.call(cbind, setNames(lapply(un1, 
       function(nm) rowMeans(w2[startsWith(names(w2), nm)], na.rm = TRUE)), un1)))
```

Comment: Is [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643280/add-the-same-density-curve-to-a-plot-in-r) suitable for you?

Comment: @Reza may be you could use the `panel` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949766/how-to-add-abline-with-lattice-xyplot-function)

Comment: In my question the same independent curve is being added to the xyplot, that is the challange! I'm open to any other packages?

Comment: @Reza may be you need `layer` as in [here](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/man/layer.html)