# add the same density curve to a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I was wondering how I could add the same density curve to an `xyplot()` from `lattice` package in R (*see reproducible code below*)?

```
library(lattice)

xyplot((1:32*.01)~wt|gear , data = mtcars)

lines(density(rnorm(1e3, 3.5))) # add this to all plot panes in `xyplot` above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `layer`

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
foo <- xyplot((1:32*.01)~wt|gear , data = mtcars)
foo + 
      layer(panel.densityplot(rnorm(1e3, 3.5), plot.points = FALSE))
```

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61644115/coloring-the-area-under-a-curve-for-multiple-plots-in-r) is the question.