# coloring the area under a curve for multiple plots in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I was wondering if I could **color** the area under the same curves in my plots below?

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

foo <- xyplot((1:32*.01)~wt|gear , data = mtcars)
foo + 
  layer(panel.densityplot(rnorm(1e3, 3.5), plot.points = FALSE))


# By color I mean like so: 
d <- density(rnorm(1e3, 3.5));
plot(d, type = 'n');
polygon(d, col = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)    
d <- density(v1)
foo <- xyplot((1:32*.01)~wt|gear , data = mtcars)
foo +        
   layer(panel.polygon(d, col = 2, alpha = 0.3))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- rnorm(1e3, 3.5)
```

Comment: @Reza. you said earlier that you don't want the points inside the density?

Comment: @Reza you can. change the `alpha`

Comment: Can you see [*this follow-up*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61683136/adding-different-curves-to-plots-in-r)?