# adding different curves to plots in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I know I can add the **same curve** to each plot pane as a `layer` using `lattice` and `latticeExtra` R packages (*see blow*).

But suppose we wanted to add **different curves** to each plot pane.

For example, in the below example, I wonder how to add `v1` only to the *top plot*, `v2` to the *bottom-left plot*, and `v3` to the *bottom-right* plot?

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)    

set.seed(24)
v1 <- density(rnorm(1e3, 3.5))
v2 <- density(rnorm(1e3, 3))
v3 <- density(rnorm(1e3, 2.75))


foo <- xyplot((1:32*.01)~wt|gear , data = mtcars)
foo + layer(panel.polygon(v1, col = 2, alpha = 0.3))
```

[image]

Comment: It's easy to do with ggplot2 with `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`. Is there an advantage of using lattice?

Comment: Sure, thank you for asking.

Comment: Interesting. Sorry I didn't fully appreciate what you were doing. I'll work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option

```
foo + 
   layer(if(panel.number() == 3) {
            panel.polygon(v1, col = 2, alpha = 0.3)
      } else if(panel.number() == 1) {
            panel.polygon(v2, col = 2, alpha = 0.3)
      } else{
           panel.polygon(v3, col = 2, alpha = 0.3)
    })
```

[image]

#### data

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)    

set.seed(24)
v1 <- density(rnorm(1e3, 3.5))
v2 <- density(rnorm(1e3, 3))
v3 <- density(rnorm(1e3, 2.75))


foo <- xyplot((1:32*.01)~wt|gear , data = mtcars)
```

Comment: @Reza I checked the code again, sorry I couldn't get that error

Comment: @Reza these are the versions off paackages I used `packageVersion('lattice')
[1] ‘0.20.38’
> packageVersion('latticeExtra')
[1] ‘0.6.28’` and I am using only your example

Comment: @Reza yes, i created the 'v1', 'v2', 'v3' as in hyour post

Comment: @Reza it is in counter clockwise direction

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ggplot2` and `facet_grid`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# user data
v1 <- (rnorm(1e3, 3.5))
v2 <- (rnorm(1e3, 3))
v3 <- (rnorm(1e3, 2.75))

# Make df1 from user data and associate with add gear value in `mtcars`
df1 <- data.frame(wt = c(v1, v2, v3),
                gear = as.factor(c(rep(3, 1000),
                        rep(4, 1000), 
                        rep(5, 1000))))

# select data from mtcars and add user defined values (`val`)
df2 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(val = 1:32 * 0.01) %>% 
  remove_rownames() %>% 
  mutate(gear = as.factor(gear)) %>% 
  select(c(val, gear, wt))


ggplot(df2, aes(x = wt, y = val,  #set up mapping with df2
                fill = gear)) + 
  geom_density(data = df1,  #make density plots of df1
      aes(x = wt, 
          fill = gear),
      inherit.aes = FALSE) + #next add points from df1
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = wt, y = val), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(gear))
```

You can make the fill color more transparent by adding an alpha value to `geom_density`.

[image]

Comment: The revised answer uses your data and adds the points desired.

Comment: @Reza did you see this answer? Hoping it was helpful.